# Best way to convert string to DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert string to DateTimeOffset.I am using DatetimeOffset.Parse(string).Parse obviously throws an exception when string is not in correct format.It is not able to parse 0000-00-00.

I want a single line of code saying me the best possible way to tackle this situation.If input is 0000-00-00 then it should be converted to current DateTimeOffset.

Any other string also apart from 0000-00-00 that cant be parsed should be changed to DateTimeOffset.Now.

Comment: What date should the text `"0000-00-00"` parse as?

Comment: You can not change the logic of DateTimeOffset.Parse method. You can write a helper method which will check for the value "0000-00-00" and return current DateTimeOffset else try to parse the input value to DateTimeOffset and return respective value.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya So you are saying to use DateTimeOffset.TryParse?

Comment: @Enigmativity it should parse to the current datetimeoffset

Comment: @SrimanSaswatSuvankar - Ah, sorry I missed that.

Comment: Why should it parse to the current DateTimeOffset? And, if it should in your design, why not just use a simple if statement?

Comment: Why would you want this to be a single line of code? You could make anything a single line of code by wrapping it in a method...

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for

```
DateTimeOffset dto = (input == "0000-00-00" ? DateTimeOffset.Now : DateTimeOffset.Parse(input));
```

**EDIT**
Based on your clarification that all invalid dates should default to the current time, the following will do that:

```
DateTimeOffset dto;
if(!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(input, out dto))
    dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Comment: 0000-00-00 is just a sipmle case.If I give some random string also then it should convert it to DateTimeOffset.now.

Comment: @SrimanSaswatSuvankar - So any invalid input should be `DateTimeOffset.Now`? That is starting to sound weird. How do you control the input?

Comment: This is the data I am getting from an external source via API.So no way to control the data.

Comment: You need to use DateTimeOffset.TryParse for trying out any random string. Follow the answer below.

Comment: @SrimanSaswatSuvankar - This is even worse. If you can't control the external data how do you know that the date format they are sending you is a valid date but you're not parsing it right?

Comment: @Enigmativity - API is not sending me a valid date.That's why I want to parse the date.I assumed that everytime the date sent will be fine but then there was this 0 date which got caught and now I am trying to change it.

Comment: @SrimanSaswatSuvankar - It's bad practice to just turn any bad data into a default value. You really should properly handle each input.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Yes but chances of bad data is rare and If I turn into a default value then it does not hamper us in any way and it perfectly fits according to the requirements and this bad data was by chance coming from some other system which is not ours.So there is no control what can come in as input.

Answer (score 5):

You can not change the logic of DateTimeOffset.Parse method. You can write a helper method which will check for the value "0000-00-00" and return current DateTimeOffset else try to parse the input value to DateTimeOffset and return respective value

```
public class DateTimeOffsetHelper
{
    public static DateTimeOffset FromString(string offsetString)
    {

        DateTimeOffset offset;
        if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(offsetString, out offset))
        {
            offset = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }

        return offset;
    }
}
```

And you can use it as following.

```
var offsetString = "2017-05-30";
var offset = DateTimeOffsetHelper.FromString(offsetString);
```

This should help you resolve you issue.

Comment: Slight correction.It should be !DateTimeOffset.TryParse....Because if its not able to parse then its DateTimeOffset.Now

Comment: How does TryParse know "05" is month or day? What if "2017-05-04" was passed in?

Comment: Tryparse expects "05" to be month only. If that value is more than 12 the TryParse will return false. The output for "2017-05-04" will be "5/4/2017" which is "04-May-2017"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple one-liner.

```
Func<string, DateTimeOffset> parseDateTimeOffset = input =>
    input == "0000-00-00" || DateTimeOffset.TryParse(input, out DateTimeOffset output)
        ? DateTimeOffset.Now
        : output;
```

It is C#7 though.